# Не получается установить TLS соединение

Tags: c#

Собственно, не удается установить защищенное соединение с сайтом, пробовал обычный `webrequest, xnet, chilkat` - ничего не помогает, зато запрос в браузере проходит. Предположительно, причина кроется в установке сертификата(или цепочки).

вот собственно линк https://mservice-darkpod.bankofamerica.com/

Comment: В меня все работает через WebRequest, может у вас кто-то перехватывает трафик и подставляет свой сертификат?

Comment: да по началу снифер, но дело в том что со сниффером работало, а потом перестало, можно пример вашего кода?

Comment: я еще могу предполагать что не на всех машинах может работать(из-за чего не знаю)

Comment: `var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://mservice-darkpod.bankofamerica.com/");
            var resp = req.GetResponse();
            string s = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Кстати, можете подставить свой callback вот здесь, если хотите что бы со сниффером работало: `HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

Comment: Спасибо огромное работает)

Comment: Отлично, я добавил как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы работаете со снифферами, или кто-то подставляет свой сертификат, можете переопределить проверку серверного сертификата в `HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`.